# What is causing this "cannot borrow as mutable" exception?

Tags: reference, rust, mutability

Why is this exception being thrown, and how I can fix it? This is a piece of code that I am working on to get user input. I want to eventually use enums instead of if else statements, but I don't understand how to implement enums well enough yet.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let version = String::from("0.0.1");
    let mut input = String::new();

    shell(&mut input, &version);
}

fn shell(input: &mut String, version: &String) {
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
        Ok(b) => {
            if &input.trim() == &"ver" {
                println!("{}", &version);
            } else {
                println!("Command '{}' Not Recognized", &input);
                shell(&mut input, &version);
            }
        }
        Err(err) => panic!("incorrect"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `input` itself is not mutable, it just contains a mutable reference, which is why you can't make a mutable reference to it.

However, since it is already a mutable reference, you can pass it directly to `read_line`, without referencing it again:

```
fn shell(input: &mut String, version: &String) {
    match io::stdin().read_line(input) {
        // already a &mut ref:  ^^^^^
```

You *could* make the variable mutable, and re-borrow it:

```
fn shell(mut input: &mut String, version: &String) {
    //   ^^^
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
```

But this shouldn't be necessary. It only works because of Rust's auto-deref rules, which allows for things like `&&&&&&T` to be treated as `&T` in some situations. This is there for convenience because a lot of generic functions return references to their inputs and it would get messy having to dereference everything.

Comment: I figured it out a few minutes later, but this makes it more clear. Thank you so much.